# how to disable one checkbox when a user check one in multicheck box

Tags: php, jquery

I have two checkboxes generated like this:

```
  <table>
    <?php foreach ($invited_members as $mem) : ?>
        <?php if ($mem['mc_role'] != 'c') : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"> attend  </td>
                             <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"><input name="p_members[]" id="p_members" type="checkbox"  value="<?php echo $mem['member_id']; ?>" <?php if ($mem['mm_present'] == 1) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> <?php if (!$this->isSupervisor or $meeting_info['meeting_status'] != 2) echo 'disabled="disabled"';?> onclick="change(this,'#on_p_members');"/></td>
                              <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"> E-attend  </td>
                                <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"><input name="on_p_members[]" id="on_p_members" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $mem['member_id']; ?>" <?php if ($mem['mm_present'] == 2) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> <?php if (!$this->isSupervisor or $meeting_info['meeting_status'] != 2) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?>onclick="change(this,'#p_members');"/></td>
                                <td style="width:50px;text-align:center"><img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'avaters/' . $mem['mem_image']; ?>" height="38" width="38" /></td>
                                <td><?php echo stripslashes($mem['mem_real_name']); ?></td>
                            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
```

I want when the user check on one of the them the other on disabled so i tired using jquery

```
function change(p_members,x)
{


 if ($(p_members).attr('checked'))
     { 

         $(x).attr('checked',false);
         $(x).attr('disabled',true);

     }
     else 
         {               
              $(x).removeAttr('disabled');

         }
  }
```

But it didn't work correctly. When the user in the second row check one the checkbox, one of the checkboxes on the row before it is disabled. How can I solve this ?

Comment: in your second checkbox you may have a typo .. you say `disabled"'; ?>onclick=` you have not a space. `disabled"'; ?> onclick=` (notice the space)

Comment: moreover you are looping in a foreach but you use every time the same id. That is not accepted. You print more than one elements with the same id i.e. `id="p_members"`

Comment: ok @antoniom i think you are right how can i slove this issue

Comment: @jessh radio didn't work the way i need it it moves form the first row to the second how can i make it only for the specific row ??

Comment: first you must assign different ids on each element. You can do that by altering foreach to `foreach ($invited_members as $index => $mem)` and then altering the ids in order to be individual e.g. `id="p_members_" . $index`

Comment: use a different name attribute for each row of radio buttons. The first row will all have name='row1', the second, name='row2' and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

```
 $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").not($(this)).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

This is a general form. you can add parent of element or id to get desired checkbox list.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it on any version of jQuery:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="p_members" />
<input type="checkbox" id="on_p_members" />
```

JavaScript

```
$('#p_members').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#on_p_members').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#on_p_members').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle to see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/s3pRy/

Comment: it works only for the fist row and didn't work for the second

Comment: sorry I didn't realize you had multiple rows since you were using ID for both elements. Since IDs in HTML are supposed to be unique if you change "on_p_members" to be a class instead and change "#on_p_members" to ".on_p_members" in the JavaScript it should work correctly for multiple "on_p_members" rows